# Swift XCTAssertEqual (Float) fails when directly passing getter

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I've run into a very strange bug with Xcode's Swift unit testing. When I store the `Float` value of a getter, it works, but when I pass the same getter to `XCTAssertEqual`, it fails because the value the XCT function receives is `0`, not the actual calculated value (in this case `800`).

Has anyone run into this?

```
// Rectangle.width = get { return left - right }

let w = metrics.imageDestinationRectangle.width
let h = metrics.imageDestinationRectangle.height

// these work okay
XCTAssertEqual(w, 800, accuracy: 0.001) 
XCTAssertEqual(h, 533, accuracy: 0.001)

// these fail: "0" is not equal to "800"
XCTAssertEqual(metrics.imageDestinationRectangle.width, 800, accuracy: 0.001)
XCTAssertEqual(metrics.imageDestinationRectangle.height, 533, accuracy: 0.001)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what happened but I did some other related coding, then tried putting the getters directly into the XCTAssertEqual parameters and it succeeded. None of the code changed. Strange!